# Restrict guest Wi-Fi to Internet

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, wifi-hotspot

First, I am not an expert in Unix/Linux, but I know my way around.

I used [this link](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software) to set up my Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian jessie) to have a access point on the Wi-Fi interface, which reroutes through the Ethernet interface. It does so correctly and it wasn’t much trouble.

My goal is to make it a guest Wi-Fi access point that reroutes traffic only to and from the outside world, to shield it from all devices on the local network, including other guests on the access point.

I have tried searching on the Internet, but couldn’t find particularly what I need. I am under the impression that it should be sufficient to add/alter the `iptables` rules on the Raspberry Pi, based on what I did find. But I couldn’t figure out exactly what rules to add. I have tried to figure out what the different rules I found online do exactly, but even with the `iptables` manpages, I wasn’t able to transcode which rule exactly did what and catered to which needs of the user.

Examples of questions/links of which I have tried to decipher the rules:
[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/517490/securing-a-guest-vm-to-give-it-internet-access-but-block-access-to-host-lan), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46104/how-to-provide-a-guest-lan-on-one-ethernet-device), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/616642/how-to-use-nat-iptables-rules-for-hostapd)

My question is the following: What rules should I add to get the behavior I described? Please include an explanation of what each of them does.

My current set of rules is as follows:

```
$ iptables -S    
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

$ iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I have not touched other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict guest Wi-Fi to Internet: block the private networks 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16 for your wireless interface.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how I would go about doing that?